# Is tag "trajectory" necessary?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

FYI, I created a new tag, [trajectory](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trajectory). I thought I should ask it not if I was too lame to ask before creating, so there wouldn't be too late to delete it in case.

Is this tag necessary or is tag [orbit](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbit) enough? (there's not even so clear for me the difference between the two worlds)

Comment: This was resolved by getting rid of the trajectory tag, despite the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable to have both, in my opinion. They aren't really the same thing. Orbit might be considered of course as a type of trajectory (i.e. orbital trajectory), but what's usually implied with the latter is non-orbital trajectories, such as parabolic-, hyperbolic-, ballistic-,... So yeah, I say we keep them both, see if they later need further differentiation.

By the way, that question you tagged with [trajectory](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trajectory), I'm not sure it really needs it, since it already uses [orbit](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbit) and you're specifically asking about *orbital trajectories*.   There might be a point in making [orbit](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbit) a synonym of [trajectory](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trajectory) tho, but that's probably best asked as a different question, or just asked of community managers moderating the site now through flags on your question. @JonEricson is experienced and knowledgeable enough on the subject to simply do it with respect to what's best for the community, if prompted to it by a flag, I have no doubt. ;)